# add blank attribute in magento backend and use php to calculate the value

Tags: magento-1.7, product, magento-1.6, backend

i have added a new atribute called frontend_price in magento's backend in the manage product selection.

In the value of this attribute would like to get the product's price and multiply it with the Vat tax and the currency. Nothing fancy just to se the product's frontend price in the backend, but not stored into any table of the db. This attribute is for internal porpose only, so it does not have to be visible in the frontend.

i was thinking of :

```
Mage::app()->loadAreaPart(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_FRONTEND,Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::PART_EVENTS);
$currencyrate = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyRate(); 
$price_normal = $_product->getPrice();
$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('frontend_price')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) = $price_normal*$currencyrate*1.24;
```

Unfortunatly i don't know where to implement this code to see it in the backend. Any ideea where to edit the page for the backend product selection page.

Thank you.

Comment: hey could you help me with this problem i have as i saw you had the same one in the stack exchange site but im not allowed to comment in there as i dont use it so dont have enough reputation.

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40395/exporting-a-csv-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a backend model for this, first you need to create the attribute (in your module setup script):

```
// This attribute will get installed in all attribute sets
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'frontend_price', 
    array(
       'type'                          => 'decimal',
       'label'                         => 'Frontend price',
       'class'                         => '',
       'global'                        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
       'backend'            => 'feprice/entity_attribute_backend_feprice',
       'visible'                      => true,
       'required'                   => true,
       'user_defined'           => false, // this is what determines if it will be a system attribute or not
        'default'                   => '',
        'searchable'            => false,
        'filterable'                => false,
        'comparable'            => false,
        'visible_on_front'      => false,
        'unique'                    => false
       ));
```

Next you create the backend model:

```
class My_FrontendPrice_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Feprice extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Abstract {

    public function beforeSave($object) {
        // This is where we would perform the audit (or any other logic we wanted)
        // We could email the changes to a store admin, for example
        $currencyrate = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyRate(); 
        $price_normal = $object->getPrice();

        $object->setFrontendPrice($price_normal*$currencyrate*1.24);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Now the frontend price will be updated every time you save your product.

Code is based on the snippet from: http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/using-a-backend-model-to-customize-magento-a-tip-from-magento-developers-paradise/

Comment: yaips i was hoping for a simple code to modify the core files to help be but... i'll try it you way ( step 1 - learn to make a magento module, step 2 - implement your code ) - be back with feedback

Comment: You can look at my Product Profit extension, this does almost the same (adds an attribute and calculates on save of a product), you can use the source as a base and then change it to your needs. See https://bitbucket.org/genmato/productprofit/overview

Comment: first off all congrats on a nice pice of kit, tried it but it dosent work for me (magento 1.6.2.0) the module does exactly what i'm trying to do.. i'm troubleshooting it now.. for some reason it does not add the attributes to magento (product_profit and product_profit_ratio)

Comment: I used the install-{version}, if you rename them to mysql4-install{version}.php it should work (did not try it myself).

Comment: just got it to work - it works briantly, now i have to load the frontend currency and multiply so it will show my frontend price corectly ( the base currency is in euro and the frontend is in ron)

Comment: works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event `catalog_product_save_before` and in your method that handles this event add something like this:

```
public function catalog_product_save_before($observer){
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $frontendPrice = ...Your algorithm here
    $product->setFrontendPrice($frontendPrice);
}
```

Now, each time you save a product the attribute `frontend_price` will be calculated and even if you have a field for it in the backend, it's value will be recalculated at each save process.

Comment: salut Marius, first off all let me give you my congrats for Ultimate Module Creator, i understand it's a must have for any magento admin and secondly i was hoping to give it a try, maybe even regarding the current question, but i see it's only for 1.7 and i'm using 1.6, hence the question will it work for 1.6.2.0 ?

Comment: @Rasvan The code in the answer should work for any Magento version. even for 1.0...I think.