# Exporting a CSV File

Tags: magento-1.9, csv, export

I need to export a CSV file with all the product weights on it, i tried to do it in the back end but i get this error

Request Timeout

This request takes too long to process, it is timed out by the server. If it should not be timed out, please contact administrator of this web site to increase 'Connection Timeout'.

Is there a way i can do this via SSH or through a script?

Thank you

Comment: To debug these problems, please read https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this:

**In Magento Admin Panel**

Go to  System -> Import/Export -> Dataflow Profiles -> Export All Products

**There you should be able to customize which attributes to export**

It will by default export to /var/export

Please let me know if this works for you

Comment: I had to do it this way and just export it in small chunks as we have to many products. Also had to get my server provider to up my connection time to the max

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using Dataflow Profiles itself as others said. Or in another way you can use the following script to export the weight with sku.

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$iteration = 0;
$saveData = array();
ob_start();
header('Content-type: application/utf-8');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="exportweights.csv"');
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w'); 
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
foreach ($products as $product) {
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
$saveData['sku'] = $_product->getSku();
$saveData['weight'] = $_product->getWeight();//Configurable product will return empty  
if($iteration==0) fputcsv($fp, array_keys($saveData));
fputcsv($fp, $saveData);
$iteration++;
}
?>
```

Note: CSV file will get downloaded to your PC.

Answer (score 0):

Just raise the `max_execution_time` of php. Either via `ini_set()` or `.htaccess`

You could do it in the apache configuration too, but you want to restore the setting.

Comment: tried adjusting the .htaccess but it still timed out

Comment: read the link I posted aboce and check the logs.